# How to convert an attribute to a reference in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails and I am working on an existing project in which I think some of the attributes of the models should be changed to be independent models; then they should referenced in the  original models. What are the needed tasks to do this? Should I first remove those columns and then generate new models based on the attributes or there is easier way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to automatically spin off attributes into a separate model definition.

If there's existing data that you want to preserve, then create the new model with a migration and with a foreign key to the original model, and then write code to transfer the data.

```
Primary.each do |p|
  p.secondary = Secondary.new
  p.secondary.attribute_1 = p.attribute_1
  p.secondary.attribute_2 = p.attribute_2
  p.secondary.save
end
```

Then delete the primary attribute_1 and attribute_2 columns

If there is no existing data you need to preserve, then just create the new model and delete the old attributes using migrations.